# Sorting by a name field?

Tags: sort

I am trying to sort the following file

http://pastebin.com/EqA2SUMy.

But the part I am trying to sort is the 11 field and only if the first field is atom. Here is an example

```
  ATOM     33  CG  ASP A 438       8.283  24.407 131.412  1.00 17.18           C  
 ATOM     34  OD1 ASP A 438       9.153  23.597 131.783  1.00 17.73           O  
 ATOM     35  OD2 ASP A 438       7.530  25.009 132.208  1.00 18.39           O  
 ATOM     36  N   PHE A 439       5.102  23.813 128.903  1.00 12.35           N  
 ATOM     37  CA  PHE A 439       3.680  23.598 129.138  1.00 12.15           C
```

I know how to sort a file based on fields. For example for my file it would be

```
            sort -k11 <\file path >
```

sort based on the eleventh field but how do I make it sort only if first field is atom b/c there are fields that go to 11 and start with HETATM and such.

Comment: It looks like the ATOM and HETATM lines are sorted on the 2nd field and are interspersed. Do you need HETATM lines to still be interspersed with ATOM lines after the ATOM lines are sorted? If so, by what sorting criteria? If not, can you separate the file into two files - one with ATOM, one not - then sort the ATOM file, then combine the two files together?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No I do not need the HETATM lines, only the ATOM.

Comment: The sorting criteria is on the 11 field,  it is based on the ascending order.

Comment: The sort list must only be the ATOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, if I understood correctly, you only want the lines starting with `ATOM`.

```
sort -k11 <(awk '$1 ~ /ATOM/' file)
```

Explanation:

- `sort -k11`: sort by the 11th field
- `awk '$1 ~ /ATOM/' file`: only prints the fields startig with `ATOM`
- The `awk` part is the input to the `sort` part

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!

Comment: well actually it does work, it print all the atom fields and the eleventh order in descending order.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez wasn't that what you wanted? For reverse order use `sort -k11 -r`.

Comment: Yes it was, I was describing the output.

Comment: It might be better to use `awk '$1=="ATOM"' file` so that if you have cases where `$1` can be `ATOMIC` they will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

How would you like the end result to look like? Should all the rows with first field ATOM appear at the top of the file, end of file?

If it's okay to have the ATOMs anywhere in the list, then a possible way is to sort them in a different file and append to top or bottom of the original file, or a specific column. I'm sure someone else will post an easier solution - just my two cents for now..

```
grep -v ^ATOM file > result; sort -k11 < grep ^ATOM file >> result
```